# Why does this Facebook page can't be displayed within a StageWebView?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, air, stagewebview

By trying to open the website `https://www.facebook.com/nike` within a `StageWebView`, I received the following error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: console  at
>   https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y2/r/KK4271o6DmT.js : 95
>   TypeError: Result of expression 'bigPipe' [undefined] is not an
>   object.

The website stopped loading and couldn't be displayed completly.

This is the Air/AS3 code I'm using:

```
var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
webView.stage = this.stage;
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
webView.loadURL("https://www.facebook.com/nike")
```

How to get to load the website within StageWebView completely?
(Is there a way to ignore the errors?)

I'm using Flash CS6 and Adobe Air 3.9

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Embedded WebKit issue, you can Switch your webkit engine from Embedded to System browser engine. I tested using system browser its working fine, because it take our systems browser, you can switch your webkit engine by StageWebView( true ).

```
 private var webView : StageWebView;

 webView  = new StageWebView( true );
 webView.stage = this.stage;
 webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 0, 1024, 768 );
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this also working on mobile (Android, iOS) or only on desktop?

Comment: In mobiles, stagewebview always pick from system webkit only, so it should work on mobiles.

Comment: Am using both ios and android. This is working for me, so you can try this method.